# How to separate the response in hyper?

Tags: http, rust, response, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm implementing the http listener with rust hyper, I wondering how can I separate the response from the `handle_request()`. Here is my code snippet.

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {

//...//

tokio::spawn(process_data(rx.clone(), processor_args, tokenizer.clone()));

    let addr = ([172, 17, 0, 4], 6006).into();
    let cookie_jar = CookieJar::new();
    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
        let cookie_jar = cookie_jar.clone();
        let vec_queue = vec_queue.clone(); 
        let tx = tx.clone();
        let tokenizer = tokenizer.clone();
        async move {
            let handle_request_task = tokio::task::spawn(async move {
                service_fn(move |req| {
                    handle_request(req, cookie_jar.clone(), tx.clone(), vec_queue.clone(), tokenizer.clone())
                })
            });
            core::result::Result::Ok::<_, hyper::Error>(handle_request_task.await.expect("failed to spawn handle_request task"))
        }
    });

}


async fn handle_request(
    req: Request<Body>,
    mut cookie_jar: CookieJar,
    tx: Sender<IdsWithToken, i32>,
    vec_queue: Arc<Mutex<VecDeque<IdWithMessage>>>,
    mut tokenizer: Tokenizer,
) -> Result<Response<Body>, anyhow::Error> {
    
    //...//

    let request_message = IdsWithToken {
        session_id: session_id.clone(),
        token: token.clone(),
    };
    println!("request_message: {:?}", request_message);
    let _ = tx.send(request_message.clone(), 0).await;


    if let Some(final_response) = process_response_from_queue(vec_queue.clone(), request_message.session_id.clone()).await {
        Ok(Response::new(Body::from(format!(
            "Data from priority queue: {}",
            final_response.message
        ))))
    } else {
        Ok(Response::new(Body::from(
            "No data available in the priority queue",
        )))
    }
}
```

At now, `handle_request()` receiving the request of clients and returning the response to client. But I want to return nothing at `handle_request()`, I just want to return the response at another thread like below.

```rust
tokio::spawn(response_worker(/*...*/));
// I want to return the response of request at response_worker()
```

I think `service_fn()` of hyper must need `Result<Response<Body>, _>`. Then, is there any other way that separate the request and response?

Comment: maybe this example will help you there is the use of the service_fn function there - https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/blob/master/examples/service_struct_impl.rs

Comment: According to [this section in Async Programming Rust Book](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html?highlight=switch#awaiting-on-a-multithreaded-executor) ,  async runtime executor could switch each `Future` object  between threads , you can simply write another function like `async fn gen_http_response(...)` , call it and wait it until it is complete in `handle_request(...)`  . Even if you explicitly spawn the part to different task  , I haven't found any method to force the task to different thread in async runtime implementation like `tokio` .